# JSONObject to string without causing string encapsulation

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am having trouble finding the right way to append strings into a valid json format

```
String json = jackson.writeValueAsString(outputMap.get(AI3Constants.T1_DATA));
String T1_DATA = json.substring(1, json.length() - 1); 
//thought this would get rid of the extra ""
// T1_DATA = {"columns":["task_id","subtask_id","vin_nbr", ... ]}
JSONObject map = new JSONObject();
map.put("T1_DATA", T1_DATA);
map.put("VIN", "....");

KafkaOutputProducer.getInstance().sendRecordToResistanceInputKafkaTopic(sessionId,    jackson.writeValueAsString(map).replace("\\","")));
```

I am trying to send the map to kafka and once I convert the map to string it encapsulates T1_DATA like this:

```
{"VIN":"1GYKPMRK7PZ000965","T1_DATA":"{"columns":["task_id","subtask_id", ...]}"}
```

I've tried every combination but I don't seem to get send a valid json due to this wrapping

```
"{" .... "}"
```

I've also tried LinkedHashMap, HashMap to add the data but nothing works
I've even tried to do `.replace(""{", "{")` but I can't find the right way to send the regex

Comment: Show how you want to string to actually look like.

Comment: I don't see how this is a Kafka question. 1) Don't use substring or replace. If you need to remove escape characters, then use readValue method to parse the data 2) Are you using Kafka JSON or StringSerializer? If JSON, then it'll convert an object to bytes for you, so you should not call writeValueAsString first

Comment: why do you use both jackson and JSONObject?

Answer (score 0):

> send a valid json due to this wrapping "{" .... "}"

`{"T1":"x"}` is as valid as `{"T1":"{}"}` or `{"T1":"{\"x\"}"}`. In the latter case, when you parse the value of T1, you will end up with **a string** of `{"x"}`... If you start replacing/removing characters, only then will you start getting invalid JSON

If you want T1 to be **an object**, such as `{"T1":{"columns":[]}}`, then create a POJO, for example

```
class T1 {
  private String[] columns;

  // TODO: constructor, getter, setter, hashcode, equals, toString
} 
class RecordValue {
  @JsonProperty("T1_DATA");
  private T1 t1_data;
  @JsonProperty("VIN");
  private String vin;

  // TODO: constructor, getter, setter, hashcode, equals, toString
}
```

Then use StringSerializer for Kafka producer and

```
RecordValue v = new RecordValue();
... 
send("topic", objectmapper.writeValueAsString(v));
```

If you only want to use JsonObject class, you need to use two of them. One for the outer object, and one for T1 data value, not a String variable. However, the Jackson equivalent class is JsonNode/ObjectNode

Comment: thanks a lot! creating a POJO class worked

Comment: Glad to hear! Feel free to accept the answer using checkmark next to the post